# PHPUnit TestListener does not work in PhpStorm

Tags: symfony, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm using Symfony 2, PHPUnit 3.7.10 and PhpStorm 5.0.4.

I have a class **MyTestListener** (implements **PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener**) in the `namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Tests`.

When I call phpunit from CLI with `vendor/bin/phpunit.bat -c app/`
The listener work, the test is successful.

I found this: [PHPUnit, PHPUnit_Framework_TestListener, Netbeans and the PHPUnit xml config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067180/phpunit-phpunit-framework-testlistener-netbeans-and-the-phpunit-xml-config) but it seems to be another problem.

But when I start the test in PhpStorm the, the listener does not load, some objects should be injected into an abstract test class, which are null in this case. I also notices, that when I debug with a breakpoint in the MyTestListener class the debugger doesn't stop in this class, others breakpoints work fine.

the phpunit.xml entry:

```
    <listeners>
       <listener class="Acme\DemoBundle\Tests\MyTestListener" file="../src/Acme/DemoBundle/Tests/MyTestListener.php">
       </listener>
    </listeners>
```

I also try to add a empty  element, it doesn't help.

In my Run/Debug Configuration of PhpStorm I specify **phpunit.xml** and the **bootstrap** file.
I also add this option for the Command Line/Interpreter: `-d auto_prepend_file=vendor/autoload.php`

The listener configuration in phpunit.xml seems to be parsed, but not work. When I change the class name to an invalid file/class, I get an error, that the file can't open the stream. I also try to use a absolute file path or change the slashes into backslashes, nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a shame... I found my own error

I do all tests from CLI, but in PhpStorm only one test class, so the suite name was different and in my listener class I do the stuff only if the suite name match:

```
if ($suite->getName() == "db-tests") {...}
```

So the solution was to extends the expression to

```
$name = $suite->getName();
if ($name == "db-tests" || 
   strpos($name, 'Acme\DemoBundle\Tests\Database') !== false) {...}
```